# calculating the slope of a line in a graph

Tags: linear-algebra

could you tell me why we calculate first the y value then the x value and divide it for finding the slope.why couldn't we calcuate the x value first and then the y value and divide it.Basically is there any proof for slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a convention to use the tangent function for the slope rather than the cotangent. It could be done otherwise, but it isn't. Since it is a convention, you won't find a proof for it.

Two reasons, though, why it makes sense, and makes calculations more convenient.

First, it makes a line parallel with the $x$-axis have slope $0$ rather than "undefined" or infinite. Since this fact is used in optimisation problems, it is useful to have a defined value for the slope of a horizontal line.

Second, in the equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$ written with $x$ as the independent variable, $m$ can be read off as the slope. Using the cotangent instead would make the slope equal to $\frac 1m$. Why make life difficult?

So this convention has been chosen for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Slope refers to how far up the vertical axis the line travels as we go down the horizontal.

What you are suggesting is how much the line travels horizontally per increase in height.

To get a sense of why we define slope the way we do, we have to think about what the $x$ and $y$ variables represent. $y$ is typically the dependent variable, which means it changes as a result of the independent one, $x$. Now, because it is dependent, it is natural to represent how the line is changing in terms of how much $y$ is changing due to $x$. That is why we do rise over run.

For example, say the line rises $2$ for every unit we travel horizontally. Then $y = 2x$, because every $x$ causes an increase of $2$ in $y$. Notice that this slope is $\frac{2}{1}$.

If we were to make $x$ the dependent variable, then your definition would make sense.

In mathematical sense, we have

$$ y = \frac{y_f - y_i}{x_f - x_i}x, $$ but if we rearrange we get

$$ x = \frac{x_f - x_i}{y_f - y_i}y.$$

See how that works?

Comment: thanks for your anwser.if we use x as the dependent variable what would be the equation for slope.

Comment: Just as I defined it. We would have $x = \frac{\triangle x}{\triangle y}y + b$ where b is the x intercept instead of the y-intercept. Note that $\triangle x$ means change in x and likewise for $\triangle y$.

Comment: can we say slope is difference in x by difference in y for the anwser you gave.

Comment: If you are making $x$ the dependent variable, then yes.

Comment: okay thanks for your comments.